# Match optional domain within string

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I've racked my brain over this JS regex and have so far only managed to get parts of it to work or the whole thing to work in certain circumstances.

I have a string like this:

```
Some string<br>http://anysubdomain.particulardomain.com<br>Rest of string
```

The goal is to move the domain part to the end of the string, if it's there. The http part is also optional and can also be https. The TLD is always particulardomain.com, the subdomain can be anything.

I've managed to get everything into capture groups when the domain with protocol is present with this regex:

```
(.*)(https?\:\/\/[a-z\d\-]*\.particulardomain\.com)(.*)
```

But any attempt at making the domain part and the protocol part within it optional has resulted in no or the wrong matches.

The end result I'm looking for is to have the three parts of the string – beginning, domain, end – in separate capture groups so I can move capture group 2 (the domain part) to the end, or, if there's no domain present, the whole string in the first capture group.

To clarify, here are some examples with the expected output/capture groups:

INPUT:

```
Some string<br>http://anysubdomain.particulardomain.com<br>Rest of string
```

OR (no protocol):

```
Some string<br>anysubdomain.particulardomain.com<br>Rest of string
```

OUTPUT:

```
$1: Some string<br>
$2: http://anysubdomain.particulardomain.com
$3: <br>Rest of string
```

INPUT:

```
Some string<br>Rest of string
```

OUTPUT:

```
$1: Some string<br>Rest of string
$2: empty
$3: empty
```

Comment: Please update your question with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/TNSbTR/1 ?

Comment: Got the same as @Jan but used different regex. https://regex101.com/r/0fzc2N/1

Comment: The example is in the string he mentioned. For what we will need a example is for last when you mentioned "in separate domain part"

Comment: @Jan That only works if the domain is present, if I delete the domain there's no match.

Comment: How about this https://regex101.com/r/QtVxpP/1 ?

Comment: @revo Same as above: No domain present = no match

Comment: If there is no domain name there is nothing to move to the end of the input string. Put more samples to show real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see good answer here, as you explained you need three group and set the domain to the back of the string(to be clear the entire url or only the domain e.g particulardomain.com)

You can do this:

```
//Don't know if the  <br> tag matter for you problem, suppose it not
//this is you input 
let str = "Start of string 1234<br>https://subdomain.particulardomain.com<br>End of string 99";

let group = str.split(<br>);
let indexOfDomain;
 /*moere code like a for loop or work with a in-build funcion of the array with the regExp you made /[a-z\d\-:\/]+\.particulardomain\.com/ you can validated the domain separately.

}
```

TO HAVE IN MIND:

With your solution will not work at 100%, why?

your regExp:

```
([a-z\d\-:\/]+\.particulardomain\.com)(.*)
```

will mach a http, https, *(any other thing that is not a protocol) and will not work for this input you can test if you like and do a comment 
`Start of string 1234<br>End of string 999`

The regExp that @Valdi_Bo answer:

```
(.*?)((https?:)?\/\/[a-z\d\-]+\.particulardomain\.com)(.*)
```

will fit to the what you described in the question

*This regExp don't fit all yours input maybe he did not test it for all your input as you did not explained in your question like you did in your own answer*

In conclusion at the end you need to extract the domain (wich don't know if is the entire url as you mix up the idea). If you are not going to use the 
 do a split and then validated the regExp it will be more easy

Comment: I would change `(s*)` to `s?`. Capturing group is not needed and
either `*` or `?` pertains to the element just before, in this case
the previous char (s).

Answer (score 0):

One mistake in your regex is that it contains only `particular` whereas
the source text contains `particulardomain`, but this is a detail.

Now let's move to the protocol part. You put only one `?` (after `s`),
which means that **only** `s` is optional, but both `http` and `:`
are still required.

To make the whole protocol optional, you must:

- enclose it with a group (either capturing or not),
- make this group optional (put `?` after it).

And now maybe the most important thing: Your regex starts with `(.*)`.
Note that it is **greedy** version, which:

- initially tries to capture the whole rest of source string,
- then moves back one char by one, to allow matching by the
  following part of regex.

Change it to **reluctant** version `(.*?)` and then **optional**
group `(https?:)?` will match as expected.

Another detail: `\` before `:` is not needed. It does not do
any harm either, but due to the principle "Keep It Simple...",
I recommend to delete it (as I did above).

One more detail: After `[a-z\d\-]` (subdomain part) you should put
`+`, not `*`, as this part may not be empty.

So the whole regex can be:

```
(.*?)((https?:)?\/\/[a-z\d\-]+\.particulardomain\.com)(.*)
```

And the last remark: I am in doubt, whether you really need **three**
capturing groups. Maybe it would be enough to leave only the content
of the middle capturing group, i.e.:

```
(https?:)?\/\/[a-z\d\-]+\.particulardomain\.com
```

Comment: Good catch with the non-matching domain name, but that was just an error in the post, which I just fixed. Will test the regex you provided.

Comment: Just tested and as with earlier suggestions, when there's no domain present, there are no matches: https://regex101.com/r/GCxo7g/1

Comment: The second capturing group in my (and your) solution is **required**. Make this group optional ("?" after it) and if domain is absent, then the third group will catch the whole text. But consider another solution: It the regex failed to match, then the whole source text should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Still no dice:
https://regex101.com/r/GCxo7g/2 (works)
https://regex101.com/r/GCxo7g/3 (matches whole string)

Comment: Look at your post, second OUTPUT section. If the domain is absent, then your required output group 1 should match also **the whole string**. The only detail in which my solution (with "?" after the 2nd group) differs from your required result is that the whole text is in group 4 (instead of 1). See the "Match Information" area in the right part of *regex101* page.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Since, as stated, the goal is to move the domain to the end of the string, if it's present, I'm just matching the domain and anything after it. If there's no domain, nothing matches and hence nothing gets replaced. The problem was the two .* both at the beginning and the end of the regex. Only the one at the end is needed.

REGEX:

```
([a-z\d\-:\/]+\.particulardomain\.com)(.*)
```

Works for the following strings:

Domain present:

```
Start of string 1234<br>https://subdomain.particulardomain.com<br>End of string 999
```

Domain without protocol:

```
Start of string 1234<br>subdomain.particulardomain.com<br>End of string 999
```

No domain:

```
Start of string 1234<br>End of string 999
```

Thanks everyone for helping me rethink the problem!